# Get distinct value of column with date check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a table `ErrorLog` with following fields

```
Id - Primary key 
Message- varchar(200) 
CustomerId - int 
CreatedDate - DateTime
```

Everytime a Logged in user gets an error, it is logged in `ErrorLog` table.

Now i want to fetch *distinct Message* along with *all other fields* where CreatedDate is equal to `getdate()-1`.

**For Example:**
If i have these values in my table
[image]

then i should get output as

[image]

after query.

I'm not able to get distinct Message value by CreatedDate. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
with cte as(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by Message order by CreatedDate desc, CustomerID) as rn from Table
    where CreatedDate < cast(getdate() as date) and CreateDate >= dateadd(dd, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
)

select * from cte where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,I want to fetch all fields

Comment: @SidM, just select all columns. Edited

Comment: It doesn't work.. Message values are repeated then :(

Comment: Do you know what you want? Do you want distinct messages or distinct combinations of all columns? Correct your question with test data and desired output.

Comment: plz check the updated question, added example for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You need a ROW_NUMBER to find the latest row per message:

```
select Id, Message, CustomerId, CreatedDate
from 
 (
   select Id, Message, CustomerId, CreatedDate,
      row_number () 
      over (partition by Message
            order by CreatedDate desc) as rn
   from ErrorLog
   where your-condition-here
 ) as dt
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the distinct messages by user, you can but you cannot bring as well the id or the created date from obvious reasons (there could be to identical messages for different ids or dates):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CustomerId, Message
WHERE
  -- YourFilter here
```

DateTime contains the time part of the date as well, so unless you are trimming it is probably not matching with getdate() - 1.

Try to filter like this:

```
WHERE
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreatedDate, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GetDate() - 1, 112)
```

The convert function will make any index on the createdDate column unusable but should to the trick.

Maybe you want to return the queries from just one day, in which case the filter should be different and you can include the date on the distinct (after removing the time part) without problems.

Comment: I've tried this `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1,103)` , however its the second challenge, first is to get distinct Message with all fields

Comment: Edited to cover that.

Comment: plz check the updated question, added example for more clarification.